# Edge-preserving Image Stacking Method

Tags: opencv, edge-preserving-filter

I have been working on restoring some old stereographic images. This means I have a Left and Right image of effectively the same thing with different elements of wear on the image for each side. I had the idea that this might give some boosts in terms of using image comparison for denoising - but given the Left and Right nature of the images, the perspective would need to be preserved. Are there any methods that would perform this kind of edge-preserving image comparison denoising? I have searched and haven't been able to find any and I wonder if it exists. I found the method cv.fastNlMeansDenoisingMulti() in OpenCV, however, in the documentation this appears to change the angle of the noisy frame to match the none noisy frame (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d69/tutorial_py_non_local_means.html) which would ruin the stereoscopic effect.

The image below shows a slice of an image as an example - and the highlighted area shows that the same area in the right image is relatively undamaged, while the left area contains damage.

[image: example stereographic image]

I can fairly easily write code to split the images up into left and right - and even to go through each image in smaller chunks and match it to the correct area in the opposing image. I would love any suggestions as to algorithms or methods that I could then apply to matching chunks.